# Pandas dataframe replace the character in specific positions, without changing similar characters on other positions

Tags: python, pandas

There is a column `(‘A’)` in dataframe with the length of 3 to 8.
For the ones with the length of 6, I need to replace the O with 0 (zero) if O is in 2nd, 4th or 6th character of the string.
For example:

```
OOMOOO to O0M0O0
O4MOP8 to O4M0P8
H4M2SO to H4M2S0
```

The following code only works for the 6th character: (last character when the length is 6)

```
df['A'] = df[(df['A'].str.len() == 6)]['A'].str.replace('O$', '0')
```

Any idea how to achieve this goal for the 2nd and 4th positions?

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this using apply:

```
def replace_chars(x):
    return "".join(["0" if chr == "O" and ind%2 ==0 else chr for ind, chr in enumerate(x)])

m = df['A'].str.len() == 6 
df.loc[m, 'A'] = df.loc[m, 'A'].apply(replace_chars)
```

Edit: change assignment syntax to avoid chaining, thanks to jezrael

Comment: Thanks Sven. For the even positions, I changed ind%2 == 0 to ind%2 == 1. It worked fine and my issue is solved now.